# How to prove the limit formula of the second order partial derivative?

Tags: limits, derivatives, partial-derivative

Consider following limit formula of the second order partial derivative of a function $f(x,y,z)$:

> $$\frac{\partial^2f(x,y,z)}{\partial x^2}=\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+\Delta x,y,z)-2f(x,y,z)+f(x-\Delta x,y,z)}{(\Delta x)^2}.$$

In order to prove this formula, I start with the first order derivative:
$$\frac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial x}=\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+\Delta x,y,z)-f(x,y,z)}{\Delta x}.$$

How do I proceed now? The second derivative is the limit of the difference quotient of the first derivatives. But then I start messing up different limit operators with different variables that go to 0.

Comment: $y$ and $z$ are "constants" in this context.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the statement only holds if we assume that ${\partial^2 f\over\partial x^2}$ exists.  Here is a proof that avoids nested limits:

It is enough to prove this for a function of the single variable $x$ at $x_0=0$. By Taylor's theorem there is a function $x\mapsto g(x)$, continuous at $0$ with $g(0)={1\over2}f''(0)$, such that
$$f(x)=f(0)+x\>f'(0)+x^2 g(x)\ .$$
It follows that
$$f(x)-2f(0)+f(-x)=x^2\bigl(g(x)+g(-x)\bigr)\ ,$$
and therefore
$$\lim_{x\to0}{f(x)-2f(0)+f(-x)\over x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\bigl(g(x)+g(-x)\bigr)=f''(0)\ .$$